# Facebook over USSD

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can you explain me how I can get into whitelist on Facebook?
There is not function authenticate user by e-mail and password for further use of his access_token in facebook API.

Comment: No, there is no such functionality – but what makes you think there was a whitelist for that?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmoE-g0bORU
Look on this video they get user`s login and password and after this they can send messages, update status. To use this functions need access_token of user.
In facebook api there is no such function, so i think must be whilist servers.
For what vote down question?